# Powershell: Copy files while stripping ReadOnly from each written file

Tags: powershell

I would like a copy routine which accepts potentially readonly files, but the copied destination file always comes out NOT readonly. The trouble is knowing the path of the written file in order to change it to not be read only. I'm not willing to accidentally touch a file that wasn't moved by this copy routine, so I can't just strip readonly from everything under the destination path. Do I really have reconstruct each written filepath myself so I can call set-itemproperty on it?

Is there any clean way to implement a function like Copy-Item-StripReadOnly "F:\*" "G:\", such that nothing written to G comes out with readonly, and the rest of G:\ is not touched?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `-PassThru` argument of copy-item which will pass each destination file onto the pipeline, then loop through each, stripping the readonly:

```
Copy-Item "F:\*" "G:\" -PassThru | Set-ItemProperty -name isreadonly -Value $false
```

Comment: What version of powershell is that `isreadonly` enabled in? I just assumed i had to do it the way i answered.

Comment: Awesome! -PassThru is the critical concept I was hunting for. It's much cleaner than what I was going to do. And I just tried this and it works as expected, thanks.

Comment: @Matt I thought it was like that forever. I could be mistaken however.

Comment: The Foreach isn't required e.g. `Copy-Item F:\* G:\ -PassThru | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly $false`

Comment: @KeithHill that's what I thought, then when I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: What version of Powershell?  I tried it on V4 before I posted.  Worked just fine.

Comment: BTW I actually used `Copy-Item F:\* G:\ -PassThru | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false` (dunno why I didn't just copy *that* into the comment). Note that I specify the `Value` parameter by name.  I think that for this particular parameter set, both parameter names are required for disambiguation.

Answer (score 2):

To improve on the accepted answer, if you want to recursively copy a whole directory tree:

```
Copy-Item "$sourceDirectoryName\*" $targetDirectoryName -Force -Recurse -PassThru | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
```

The -PassThru will include both files and sub-directories. Because directories do not have an IsReadOnly attribute, Set-ItemProperty will throw an exception, unless we use **-not $_.PSIsContainer** to filter out directories.

Answer (score -1):

The piece you need would be to check it the copied file is read-only and remove the file attribute which is fairly simple.

```
$attribute = [io.FileAttribute]::ReadOnly
If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname).attributes -band $attribute)
{
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname -Name attributes -Value ((Get-ItemProperty $file.fullname).attributes -bxor $attribute)
}
```

This will check if the file `$file` is read-only. If it is remove the read-only bit. Insert this either inside your pipe statement or inside your copy loop.

I know this is not a complete solution as per your question but it is not easily readable as a comment. Also you don't really show any effort in research for this. If you show us what you might have for a function so far please include it in the code.

Comment: This is the easy part. The sloppy part is getting the file paths of each file that was written. I know how to do it, I just feel like it ought to be possible in a 1-2 liner. But then again, maybe not, the more I think about it, the more I lose hope that it can be done cleanly.

Comment: zdan's answer is WAY better than this but in my defence i was trying to tell you to put this in a foreach loop that would allow to to check this for each file after a copy.

Comment: Yeah its a reasonable piece of the solution, but I was hung up on how exactly I'd get the collection of written files to foreach over. I didn't want to build a list with a bunch of Join-Paths if I could help it. I felt like something like -PassThru had to exist but I didn't know how to more clearly form the question.